# python: Convert a textfile into csv file

Tags: python

Say I want to convert a textfile (in.txt) into a csv file (out.csv) using Python.

in.txt:

```
ID: 1
Name: Jon Doe
Address: 123 Main St Anytown, USA
Age: 25
```

The output file out.csv should looks like this:

```
"ID","Name","Address","Age"
"1","Jon Doe","123 Main St Anytown, USA","25"
```

So far I have done this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import csv

f = open("in.txt")
x = f.readlines()
s = []

for i in x:
    i = i.replace(":",'"')
    j = i.replace(" ","'")
    
csvex = csv.writer(open("out.csv","w"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
csvex.writerow(s)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Will your text file always just have a single record in it? Or might it have multiple repeating blocks of text like the example you gave?

Comment: in this case there is only a single record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that would allow either a single or multiple records:

```py
def read_records(fn_in, fn_out, record_size):
    with open(fn_out, 'w') as out_f:
        write_header = True
        with open(fn_in) as in_f:
            while True:
                try:
                    rec = {
                        f'"{key.strip()}"': f'"{value.strip()}"' for key, value in
                        [next(in_f).split(':') for _ in range(record_size)]
                    }
                    if write_header:
                        write_header = False
                        out_f.write(','.join(rec.keys()) + '\n')
                    out_f.write(','.join(rec.values()) + '\n')
                except StopIteration:
                    break


read_records('in.txt', 'out.csv', 4)
```

Some explanation:

- everything sits in a function, so you can use it repeatedly and for different files and record sizes
- the `while True` loop loops forever, until a `break` statement breaks out of it
- the `try .. except StopIteration` catches when `next(in_f)` tries to read beyond the end of the file
- `rec` is created as a dictionary, which is handy in case you need to further manipulate the values or want to use the record elsewhere, although it's not strictly speaking the most efficient way to perform the task.

Comment: thank you very much but i need the quotation marks in the output file too!!

Comment: Those can be added where the key and value were stripped of any spaces, modified the answer - captured everything in a function in case you need to do it in multiple places

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a regular expression:

```
import re

data = """
ID: 1
Name: Jon Doe
Address: 123 Main St Anytown, USA
Age: 25
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'^(?P<header>[^:\n]+):\s*(?P<value>.+)', re.MULTILINE)

headers, contents = [[], []]

for m in pattern.finditer(data):
    header, content = m.groups()
    headers.append(header)
    contents.append(content)

print(headers)
print(contents)
```

Which will yield

```
['ID', 'Name', 'Address', 'Age']
['1', 'Jon Doe', '123 Main St Anytown, USA', '25']
```

You could now join these with `;` or do anything else with it. See a demo for the expression [**on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tjsnHq/1).

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be:

```
with open(FILEPATH, "r") as f:
   d = zip(*[x.strip().split(":", 1) for x in f])

for l in d:
   print(",".join(["\"{:s}\"".format(str(x).strip()) for x in l]))
```

Specifically:

- *[x.strip().split(":", 1) for x in f]* will create a list of 2-elements lists, splitting the passed lines x by ":", forcing only one split (for example, *"a:1:2".split(":", 1)* will still give a 2 dimensional list, ["a", "1:2"], given that only the first split will be done)
- unpacking using the * operator and then zipping is a nice trick used to transpose a multi dimensional list. To be clear:

  *l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]*
  *list(zip(*l))* will return *[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]*
- The final loop with the print statement simply takes care of outputting the so obtained zip object in the desired format